# script to get a string after regex and replace it on each line with a match

Tags: regex, sed

So far have been able to extract the sting between the pattern match but havent been able to extend it to print as required.

My file content:

```
my number 12345 string1 string2
my number 789 string1 string2
my number 456789023 string3 string4
```

Next command

```
sed -e "s/.*number//;s/string.*//" filename
```

gives me output

```
 12345 
 789 
 456789023
```

I need help to extend it or a better way to print output

```
my number 12345 num 12345 string1 string2
my number 789 num 789 string1 string2
my number 456789023 num 456789023 string3 string4
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it or thought about how you might do it? Which *specific* part of the problem are you stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I derive:

```
sed -r "s/number (.*) string/number \1 num \1 string/" FILE
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the sample. When I tried it I get illegal option --r

Comment: @yandd: That is GNU sed-Version 4.2.1, if you don't have the option, mask the parens: `sed "s/number \(.*\) string/number \1 num \1 string/" FILE`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/& num &/' file
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this, I get the content of the files as is

Comment: It may be the version of sed you are using. Perhaps try: `sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/& num &/' file` or `sed -E 's/[0-9]+/& num &/' file`